# Statically link QML application with Qt5 (5.13.2)

Tags: c++, qt, static, qml

I compiled Qt 5.13.2 on Linux with the following line:

`/home/Qt/5.13.2/Src/configure -release -static -ltcg -optimize-size -opensource -confirm-license -platform linux-g++ -no-pch -nomake tools -nomake tests -nomake examples -skip webengine -prefix "/home/Qt/513-static"`

Then I created a new kit in QtCreator to use this compilation. After compiling, I tried to run but I get the error

```
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-egl, wayland.
```

My application works fine with dynamic linkage. Should I change something in the .pro file to make it work with static library?

I tried to look into the official documentation, but the information is quite poor about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the compilation. I compiled using the following line and it worked:

```
configure -release -static -optimize-size -opensource -confirm-license -feature-freetype -fontconfig -c++std c++2a -no-pch -nomake tools -nomake tests -nomake examples -skip webengine -recheck-all -platform linux-g++ -ltcg -xcb -prefix "/home/vinicius/Qt/Qt-static"
```